# What is the significance of sign of Jacobian determinant of a function?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, determinant, jacobian

In [Tom Apostol calculus volume 2 (page 402)](https://archive.org/stream/CalculusTomMApostol/Calculus%20vol.%202%20-%20Tom%20M%20Apostol#page/n423/mode/2up) I found that the non zero jacobian determinant of 
a function whose components have continuous partial derivatives on a set, is either positive or negtive in the **whole set**.

> **Why does the determinant has same sign in the whole set?**

In the text I found that the sign of the **jacobian determinant** signifies whether the orientation of a curve (clock or counterclockwise) of  a curve will be **preserved** by that function (positive determinant) or not (negative determinant).

> **How to prove or disprove that the sign of the determinant signifies whether the orientation of the curve is preserved by the function or not?**

Comment: For the first question, the answer is very simple. The author assumes that the determinant of the Jacobian is continuous and that it never vanishes. Now, every continuous function that never vanishes must have a constant sign.

Comment: Thanks for the help,  What about the second question?

Comment: One more thing worth mentioning , is that I mean clockwise or counterclockwise orientation of a curve from the point of view of winding numbers , so answering from that point of view may be more helpful.